# How to add new element inside @XmlRootElement using JaxB

Tags: jaxb

I am new to jaxb. I have a scenario here I need to generate follwing XML using JAXB

```
<WCHECK>
     <ALIASES>
        <ENTRY>
            <ENABLED>No</ENABLED>
            <TYPE>AKA</TYPE>
            <TEXT>AL1 JAMMALI IMAD BEN BECHIR BEN HAMDA</TEXT>
            <NATIVE>Yes</NATIVE>
        </ENTRY> 
        <ENTRY>
            <ENABLED>Yes</ENABLED>
            <TYPE>AKA</TYPE>
            <TEXT>AL2 JAMMALI IMAD BEN BECHIR BEN HAMDA</TEXT>
            <NATIVE>Yes</NATIVE>
        </ENTRY> 
     </ALIASES>
     <PERMUTATIONS>
        <ENTRY>
            <ENABLED>No</ENABLED>       
            <TEXT>Jammali Hamda</TEXT>
        </ENTRY> 
     </PERMUTATIONS>
</WCHECKS>
```

I have created Allias.java and Permussions.java for the same

```
@Entity
@Table(name="ING_ALIAS")
public class Aliases {

    private String id;
    private String type;
    private String text;
    private boolean enabled;
    private boolean isNativeAllias;
    private VwatchDetails  vwatchDetails;

    @Id
    @Column(name="ID")
    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @Column(name="KA_TYPE")
    public String getType() {
        return type;
    }

    public void setType(String type) {
        this.type = type;
    }

    @Column(name="TEXT")
    public String getText() {
        return text;
    }

    public void setText(String text) {
        this.text = text;
    }


    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "ENTRY_ID", nullable = false)
    public VwatchDetails getVwatchDetails() {
        return vwatchDetails;
    }

    public void setVwatchDetails(VwatchDetails vwatchDetails) {
        this.vwatchDetails = vwatchDetails;
    }

    @Column(name="IS_ENABLED")
    public boolean getEnabled() {
        return enabled;
    }

    public void setEnabled(boolean enabled) {
        this.enabled = enabled;
    }

    @Column(name="IS_NATIVE_ALIAS")
    public boolean getIsNativeAllias() {
        return isNativeAllias;
    }

    public void setIsNativeAllias(boolean isNativeAllias) {
        this.isNativeAllias = isNativeAllias;
    }
```

This class generate xml file but Its missing the ENTRY> tag. I would like to know how can I add ENTRY tag For each record of Allias and Permutations. Kindly assist me on this. Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `@XmlElementWrapper` annotation to add a grouping element.  Then use the `@XmlElement` annotation to control the element name that corresponds to each item in the collection.

```
@XmlRootElement(name="WCHECK")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class WCheck

    @XmlElementWrapper(name="ALIASES")
    @XmlElement(name="ENTRY")
    private List<Alias> aliases;

    @XmlElementWrapper(name="PERMUTATIONS")
    @XmlElement(name="ENTRY")
    private List<Permutation> permutations;

}
```

Comment: Thanks Blaise , For your inputs. I tried that but I am getting runtype error.may be I am not using it appropriatly.It would be greatful if you can paste any sudo code with @xmlElementWrapper Thanks again.

Comment: @user3730042 - I think I was adding my update the same time you were commenting.

Comment: Thank you Blaise. I got the expected output due to your inputs :)